# wkhtmltopdf unnecessary white space in header

Tags: javascript, symfony, wkhtmltopdf, knp-snappy

I have created pdf with header and footer. I want to hide header and footer from 1st and 2nd page in pdf.
So I have written below javascript code:

```
<script>
        /* page counter */
        function subst() {
            var vars={};
            var x=document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
            for (var i in x) {var z=x[i].split('=',2);vars[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]);}
            var x=['frompage','topage','page','webpage','section','subsection','subsubsection'];
            for (var i in x) {
                var y = document.getElementsByClassName(x[i]);
                for (var j=0; j<y.length; ++j) y[j].textContent = vars[x[i]];

                if(vars['page'] == 1 || vars['page'] == 2){
                    // document.getElementById("header_content").innerHTML = "";
                    document.getElementById("header_content").style.border = '1px solid';
                    var element = document.getElementById("header_content");
                    element.classList.add("hidden");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Contents are hidden but it covers white space.
So how can I remove that white space from 1st and 2nd page?

Answer (score 0):

What does the CSS class 'hidden' do?

You need to set `display: none` in there.

Sounds like you are using `visibility: hidden` instead.

Comment: I have tried with both css. But still having the same problem.

Comment: Try removing all other classes before. Set: element.className = ""; Before: element.classList.add("hidden"); Hard to know without knowing all the CSS

Comment: I have also tried with removing all classes. Still having same problem.